# Solving a PG::GroupingError: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The following code gets all the `residences` which have all the `amenities` which are listed in `id_list`. It works with out a problem with SQLite but raises an error with PostgreSQL:

```
id_list = [48, 49]
Residence.joins(:listed_amenities).
          where(listed_amenities: {amenity_id: id_list}).
          references(:listed_amenities).
          group(:residence_id).
          having("count(*) = ?", id_list.size)
```

The error on the PostgreSQL version:

[image: Rails error message]

What do I have to change to make it work with PostgreSQL?

Comment: My lack of Markdown know-how made it impossible for me to include the error code in the "right" way. I thought that the image was the least evil. I looked at the other questions but couldn't find an answer for my problem.

Comment: To paste your logs as text, just indent each line by four spaces, same as with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. `references` should only be used with `includes`; it tells ActiveRecord to perform a join, so it's redundant when using an explicit `joins`.
2. You need to fully qualify the argument to `group`, i.e. `group('residences.id')`.

For example,

```
id_list = [48, 49]
Residence.joins(:listed_amenities).
          where(listed_amenities: { amenity_id: id_list }).
          group('residences.id').
          having('COUNT(*) = ?", id_list.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query the Ruby (?) code is expanded to is selecting all fields from the residences table:

```
SELECT "residences".*
  FROM "residences"
 INNER JOIN "listed_amenities"
    ON "listed_amentities"."residence_id" = "residences"."id"
 WHERE "listed_amenities"."amenity_id" IN (48,49)
 GROUP BY "residence_id"
HAVING count(*) = 2
 ORDER BY "residences"."id" ASC
 LIMIT 1;
```

From the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html), When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column.

You'll need to either group by all fields that aggregate functions aren't applied to, or do this differently.  From the query, it looks like you only need to scan the amentities table to get the residence ID you're looking for:

```
SELECT "residence_id"
  FROM "listed_amenities"
 WHERE "listed_amenities"."amenity_id" IN (48,49)
 GROUP BY "residence_id"
HAVING count(*) = 2
 ORDER BY "residences"."id" ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

And then fetch your residence data with that ID.  Or, in one query:

```
SELECT "residences".*
  FROM "residences"
 WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "residence_id"
                  FROM "listed_amenities"
                 WHERE "listed_amenities"."amenity_id" IN (48,49)
                 GROUP BY "residence_id"
                HAVING count(*) = 2
                 ORDER BY "residences"."id" ASC
                 LIMIT 1
               );
```